# sqrt decomposition of input queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I read about sqrt decomposition data structure on this site https://acmcairoscience.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/sqrt-decomposition/

I have understood the standard algo of this DS in which we divide the input array into buckets of size sqrt(N) where N is the size of the array.

But here's what I cant understand:sqrt decomposition of the input queries.

Suppose that we have some problem in which we are given some input data, and then k queries, each of which we have to process and issue a response. We consider the case when requests are as requested (do not change the state of the system, but only asks for some information) and modifying (ie affecting the state of the system is initially set to the input data).

This is the given approach which I cant understand:Split the k queries in buckets of size sqrt(k) and process all the queries in each bucket at once.

Why we decompose queries into sqrt size buckets ?? and how we can process all the queries in each bucket ??

Answer (score 0):

He's not splitting the queries into buckets, but rather logically splitting the data into buckets of sqrt(k). Then, rather than responding to each query as it's received, he re-orders the queries so that they're processed in order by range. That is, queries that start in bucket N are processed before those that begin in bucket N+1, and those that end in bucket M are processed before those that end in bucket M+1.

So the queries are processed in-order, from left to right.

If there are sqrt(n) buckets, then each bucket's size is sqrt(n). Let's say that q = sqrt(n).

Let's say that the first query just uses bucket 1. The program has to do a q^2 calculation *for the first bucket.* It then caches the results so that any other query starting in bucket 1 won't have to do the calculation again. As the program processes queries from left to right, it eventually has to do that same q^2 calculation for each bucket. If the queries end up using all of the buckets, then we did q calculations, each of which took q^2 time.

Since q = sqrt(n), then q*q^2 = sqrt(n) * n.

Comment: If he is splitting the data into buckets of sqrt(k), then there should be N/sqrt(k) buckets ?? But this is not the case. Also, how can we deal with modification queries in this offline algo ? PS: the origional site is <http://e-maxx.ru/algo/sqrt_decomposition >  but it is in russian (google chrome translate works pretty well)

Answer (score 0):

Spiting the queries works on some special cases like any other good idea.
the whole thing is about with a bucket of query you will go thought the whole array at most once using two pointers.

so the necessary condition for this is
 - if we have the answer for segment [l, r] we can easily get the answer for [l. r+1], [l+1, r], [l, r-1]

**How to prove the sqrt(Q) * k time complexity.**

-lets assume at first that you can get the answer for these segments **([l. r+1], [l+1, r], [l, r-1] )** in O(1) given the answer for the segment **[l, r]**
-since each bucket of queries the left is in an arbitrary order but the right sorted acceding so for each query in the bucket  we can make O(bucket length) iterations form moving the left pointer but for the right it can only be increased so for the whole bucket we can move the right to the end of the array only once.